# ERB template can`t get instance variables from the controller action:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have the following problem which ripped my soul for the past 2 weeks:

I want to create reports with pre-rendered html-body:

```
def new
  @content_for_prerendering= Report.get_content
  @report = Report.new
  template = ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/views/report_template/default.html.erb"))
  @report.body = template.result(binding)
end
```

following the ERB documentation. But inside the template file DEFAULT.HTML.ERB it sems like i only can see local variables like

```
 content_for_prerendering = Report.get_content
```

not instance variables. it is very unusual to bind every instance variable to local just to render some html. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to get view context binding to delegate instance vars correctly

```
@report.body = render_to_string :file => "#{Rails.root}/app/views/report_template/default.html.erb"
```

Comment: I`ll check it out in a moment! - Did you mean `render_to_string` because it complains about `render_to_text` - No Method Error?

Comment: This worked like magick but I`ve chosen `render_to_body`. Please correct your answer to something like `render_to_string` or `render_to_body`